# Replace spaces with <text:s> tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm generating ods file (OpenDocument) with XSLT.
how to replace a sequence of spaces with a tag <text:s text:c="6"/> where 6 is the number of spaces between words, if there is only one space, then replacement is not required.
Is it possible?

XML:

`<cell>CCC  GR</cell>`

`<cell>Olol lo</cell>`

---

Result:

`<text:p>CCC<text:s text:c="3"/>GR</text:p>`

`<text:p>Olol lo</text:p>`

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll phrase the question better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2, use `xsl:analyze-string`, in XSLT 3 use `analyze-string` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="cell">
    <text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., ' {2,}')" mode="match"/>
    </text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match" mode="match">
    <s count="{string-length(.)}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<root>
<cell>CCC   GR</cell>
<cell>Olol lo</cell>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
<text>CCC<s count="3"/>GR</text>
<text>Olol lo</text>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is the best solution for 2 and 3 versions

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a solution in XSLT 1.0:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:text="text" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template name="spaces">
    <xsl:param name="spaces">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with($text,' ')">
        <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
          <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$spaces + 1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text,2)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$spaces = 0"/>
          <xsl:when test="$spaces = 1">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <text:s text:c="{$spaces}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:variable name="t" select="substring-before($text,' ')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$t">
            <xsl:value-of select="$t"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
              <xsl:with-param name="spaces">1</xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cell">
    <text:p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </text:p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Thanks to your answer, there is a ready-made solution for all versions of xslt